# Without an ID, how do you handle a dropdown that could have different values based on the language?

Tags: unity-game-engine, localization, dropdown

I'm used to web dev where a dropdown has an ID field along with the text. Is there a proper way to handle associating the correct drop down value when the text could change depending on the language?

Eg. Drop down could have English and Japanese or 英語 and 
日本人. Depending on the local dialect. 
In the web world, I would have ID 1 and 2 and the text wouldn't matter. There are some ways I can see getting around it, but hoping there is a cleaner way. Will be using in a number of places with some decently large lists at times.

I've watched a few localization tutorials, but none address the issues with dropdowns and localization text.

I could build a dictionary when creating the dropdown or do a couple queries (using Sqlite), but not really as efficient as just having a unique Id associated with an option.

Comment: Suggestion, but not a perfect solution: you can extend DataOption, with a class you will call LocalizableDataOption. You can set a field "key" and create a setter so that when the key is changed it will also set the text to the localized text associated with the key. Finally, when getting an option, you can cast it to LocalizableDataOption and get the key.

Comment: Good idea, I didn't even think of trying to extend a class in Unity for some reason. Will try that first. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this for our game. Not pretty, but it works.

```
var index = 0;
MapDropdown.AddOptions(MapConfigs.Instance.Configs.Select((c, i) => {
    if(c.Id == config.Id) {
        index = i;
    }
    return new Dropdown.OptionData { text = c.Name  };
}).ToList());

MapDropdown.value = index;
MapChanged (index);
MapDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener (MapChanged);
```